# Exception thrown for cvCalcOpticalFlowHS() opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, opencv

Heey, I'm trying to sort out the function of Optical Flow of openCV, but for some reason I'm getting an exception in visual studio:

Unhandled exception at 0x772615de in Optical_flow.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0036f334..

With breakpoints I found out that the error lies within the cvCalcOpticalFlowHS function.

I'm using openCV 2.1

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

int init() {
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **args) {
  CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile("Video/Wildlife.wmv");
  double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

  CvSize size;
  size.width = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
  size.height = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

  CvVideoWriter* writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("result.avi", 0, fps,size, 1);

  IplImage* curFrame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

  Mat u = Mat(size, CV_32FC2);
  Mat v = Mat(size, CV_32FC2);

  CvTermCriteria IterCriteria;
  IterCriteria.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS;
  IterCriteria.max_iter = 500;
  IterCriteria.epsilon = 0.01;

  while(1) {
    IplImage* nextFrame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    if(!nextFrame) break;

    u = Mat::zeros(size, CV_32FC2);
    v = Mat::zeros(size, CV_32FC2);

    /* Do optical flow computation */
    cvCalcOpticalFlowHS(&curFrame, &nextFrame, 0, &u, &v, 0.01, IterCriteria);

    cvWriteFrame(writer, curFrame);

    curFrame = nextFrame;
  }

  cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
  cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

  return 0;
}
```

Anyone has seen this problem before or sees the mistake I made?

Best Regards

Remco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/legacy/doc/motion_analysis.html#calcopticalflowhs), curFrame and nextFrame should be 8-bit single channel. You are currently just pulling these from the loaded file without checking/converting them as necessary. Can you confirm that the input is of the right type?

Also you have a nasty mix of C++ style cv::Mat with C style IplImage*. I'd suggest you upgrade to a more recent version of OpenCV (2.4 has recently been released), and try to stick with the one or other of the C++ or C style methods.

Note also that this optical flow method is classed as obsolete with a recommendation to use either [calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#void%20calcOpticalFlowPyrLK%28InputArray%20prevImg,%20InputArray%20nextImg,%20InputArray%20prevPts,%20InputOutputArray%20nextPts,%20OutputArray%20status,%20OutputArray%20err,%20Size%20winSize,%20int%20maxLevel,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20flags,%20double%20minEigThreshold%29) for sparse features or [calcOpticalFlowFarneback()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#void%20calcOpticalFlowFarneback%28InputArray%20prev,%20InputArray%20next,%20InputOutputArray%20flow,%20double%20pyr_scale,%20int%20levels,%20int%20winsize,%20int%20iterations,%20int%20poly_n,%20double%20poly_sigma,%20int%20flags%29) for dense features.

Below is some example code demonstrating calcOpticalFlowFarneback(), which is what I believe you are trying to achieve. It takes data from the webcam rather than a file.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

void drawOptFlowMap(const cv::Mat& flow,
                    cv::Mat& cflowmap,
                    int step,
                    const cv::Scalar& color
                   )
{
    for(int y = 0; y < cflowmap.rows; y += step)
        for(int x = 0; x < cflowmap.cols; x += step)
        {
            const cv::Point2f& fxy = flow.at<cv::Point2f>(y, x);
            cv::line(cflowmap,
                             cv::Point(x,y),
                             cv::Point(cvRound(x+fxy.x),cvRound(y+fxy.y)),
                 color);
            cv::circle(cflowmap, cv::Point(x,y), 2, color, -1);
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **args) {

    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat newFrame, newGray, prevGray;


    cap >> newFrame; // get a new frame from camera
    cvtColor(newFrame, newGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    prevGray = newGray.clone();

    double pyr_scale = 0.5;
    int levels = 3;
    int winsize = 5;
    int iterations = 5;
    int poly_n = 5;
    double poly_sigma = 1.1;
    int flags = 0;

    while(1) {
        cap >> newFrame;
        if(newFrame.empty()) break;
        cvtColor(newFrame, newGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        Mat flow = Mat(newGray.size(), CV_32FC2);

        /* Do optical flow computation */
        calcOpticalFlowFarneback(
            prevGray,
            newGray,
            flow,
            pyr_scale,
            levels,
            winsize,
            iterations,
            poly_n,
            poly_sigma,
            flags
            );

        drawOptFlowMap(flow, newFrame, 20, CV_RGB(0,255,0));

        namedWindow("Output",1);
        imshow("Output", newFrame);
        waitKey(1);

        prevGray = newGray.clone();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is pretty similar to the fback.cpp sample code which comes with OpenCV.

Comment: On the question: I've tried to create an 8-bit single channel, atleast I think I did by using:  
---
IplImage* curGray = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
And: 
cvCvtColor(curFrame, curGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
---
Passing along the curGray/nextGray with the cvCalcOpticalFlowHS() function.
---
This has no different result.
I'm also recieving this error in the console window:
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized   or unsupported array type) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\..\ocv\opencv\src\cxcore\cxarray.cpp, line 2476

Comment: I don't have OpenCV2.1, so can't test your code directly. However, I have updates my answer with some working code using the C++ data structures in OpenCV2.3.3 (still not the most up-to-date version). The error you quote `Bad flag` is fairly common, and not very useful until you've narrowed down the particular function in your code which is at fault...