# OpenCV C++ Optical Flow based segmentation code throws Exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, opencv, opticalflow

From one of the SO answers, for segmentation using optical flow **Dense optical flow** is required. I modified [this code](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/fback.cpp?rev=2271) . It uses [calcOpticalFlowFarneback](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) function to calculate the dense flow field between two successive frames.

According to the SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399541/optical-flow-based-segmentation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329340/opencv-how-to-track-objects-after-optical-flow) , I tried to compute the magnitude of displacement  using

> sqrt(displacement_in_x^2 + displacement_in_y^2)
>
> the function returns displacement as CV_32FC2

This is my code :-

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void drawOptFlowMap(const Mat& flow, Mat& cflowmap, int step,
                    double scale, const Scalar& color)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < cflowmap.rows; y += step)
        for(int x = 0; x < cflowmap.cols; x += step)
        {
            const Point2f& fxy = flow.at<Point2f>(y, x);
            line(cflowmap, Point(x,y), Point(cvRound(x+fxy.x), cvRound(y+fxy.y)),
                 color);
            circle(cflowmap, Point(x,y), 2, color, -1);
        }
}

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap("vip.avi");


    if( !cap.isOpened() )
        return -1;

    Mat prevgray, gray, flow, cflow, frame;
    double col = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    double row = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    Mat flow_img = Mat::zeros(row,col,CV_8UC1);

    namedWindow("flow", 1);
   namedWindow("segmented",1);

   for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        if( prevgray.data )
        {
            calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, gray, flow, 0.5, 3, 15, 15, 5, 1.2, 0);
            cvtColor(prevgray, cflow, CV_GRAY2BGR);
            drawOptFlowMap(flow, cflow, 8, 1.5, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0));
            imshow("flow", cflow);
        }

        //This part I added to  compute Magnitude of flow
for(int i=0;i<gray.rows;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<gray.cols;j++)
        flow_img.at<uchar>(i,j)= cvRound(  sqrt ( pow (flow.at<Vec2f>(i,j)[0] ,2 )+ pow ( flow.at<Vec2f>(i,j)[1],2) ));

//threshold image
threshold(flow_img,flow_img,10,255,THRESH_BINARY); //some arbitrary thresh value 10

        imshow("segmented",flow_img);

        if(waitKey(30)>=0)
            break;

        std::swap(prevgray, gray);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and there are no build errors. But the program wont run and throws the following :

[image: build error]

In the console window I get :

[image: c0nsole]

I dont understand where I made the mistake. Can anyone please help me out. There were similar SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915881/exception-thrown-for-cvcalcopticalflowhs-opencv/10916530#10916530) and the answer is the code that I used. Still I get the problems mentioned above

**you can find my input video** [here](http://videobam.com/iBEAa) or [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhcMepj4vio)

Comment: Which line causes the exception? Visual studio should show it by marking it, if not check it by debugging code.

Comment: It doesnt mark anything... a window pops up showing the image(updated in my qn)... When I debug it does not show any problem...The code runs displaying output of flow vectors for few seconds and exits showing the above..

Comment: Upload somewhere thie avi file - i will check, so i can check it on my own.

Comment: i have uploaded the video file...see my edited qn above

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the line`

```
const Point2f& fxy = flow.at<Point2f>(y, x);
```

is allowed? `Point2f` is not one of the types that is described in the documentation of the `cv::Mat` class.
Try with `cv::Vec2f` as template parameter instead. You can then fill the `Point2f` variable with the result.

Next problem: in the line where you compute the 8-bit magnitude of the flow, it would be safer to use a `saturate_cast` operator:

```
flow_img.at<uchar>(i,j)= cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(cvRound(  sqrt ( pow (flow.at<Vec2f>(i,j)[0] ,2 )+ pow ( flow.at<Vec2f>(i,j)[1],2) )));
```

Not sure yet that it's causing your program to crash unfortunately.

What the error tells you is that you are calling an OpenCV function with wrong parameters. In debug mode go step-by-step in your program, so that we can know which one.

Comment: I tried as **const Point2f& fxy = flow.at<Vec2f>(y, x);** but still the code exits after few seconds...

Comment: Sorry, I completed my answer with another gotcha, but I don't think I have found the error. See the end of my answer for hints.

Answer (score 0):

The code line

```
std::swap(prevgray, gray);
```

could cause problems, since the behaviour of std::swap is

```
c(a); a=b; b=c;
```

and in that way the =operator is used, that do not apply a deep copy of your input image. Better use

```
gray.copyTo(prevgray);
```

to allocate own memory for prevgray. Else the data pointer of  prevgray points to the content of gray.